# Spotfire Webplayer greyed out.

Tags: url, spotfire

I am trying to create Web Player URL for a member of my team but this option is greyed out. Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how I can over come it.

I have added a pic below for better understanding.

As always thank you for any help you can give.

[image]

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general software tech support.

Comment: Well you are doing it on an Information link not a dxp. Is it grey on the dxp too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can't create a Web Player link for an Information Link. there's no way for it to display. the **TIBCO Spotfire URL** can be pasted into the Spotfire thick client for analysis, but you can't analyze using Web Player.

if you're trying to give your colleague access to an Information Link for analysis in Business Author, the Spotfire URL should be fine.

Comment: @ Niko: Cheers for that. New to Spotfire so still learning the ropes. Have a great day.